# binding sites to subfolder

Tags: iis, iis-8.5

I want to configure 3 intranet websites (site1, site2 and site3) running on IIS. I want to be able to use

- http://hostname/site1
- http://hostname/site2
- http://hostname/site3

In the future I also want to be able to bind

- http://nameofsite1/ -> http://hostname/site1
- http://nameofsite3/ -> http://hostname/site3

When I add my second site under the default Sites I get a message

> The binding '*:80'is assigned  to another site. If you assign the same binding to this site, you will only be able to start one of the sites. Are you sure that you want to add this duplicate binding?

I understand that IIS binds all the site to http://hostname:80/ and that it conflicts but is there a way I can configure the sites to their subfolder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in two ways.

**One:**

If you want it exactly the way you're describing, you'll need to do that using `Javascript` or `meta-refresh` and script each site to redirect users from `http://nameofsite1/ -> http://hostname/site1` etc..

You also need to configure the sites to `Require Server Name Indication` and assign each their own `Host Name`.
In this instance the `Host Name` will be `nameofsite1`

**Two:**

You still need to configure the `SNI` but you can instead set the `Physical Path`of each site to the corresponding subfolder, and you will get the results I think you mean you want.

**Note:**

Which client will be able to access the sites using `nameofsite1` will of course also depend on the DNS configuration, but I'm guessing you have that in place already?